# How do I add additional hover effect in Wordpress?

Tags: css, wordpress

I have a button that I'd like to customize differently than what I've set the global buttons.  I added the button and modified it but there is no option for editing the hover color of the button so I am trying to write additional CSS for it.

I set up a new class for the button

```
Custom-Button-Orange-to-Purple
```

but when I try to add the additional styling to this element (I did try and set up the class without the :hover and that didn't work either).

```
.Custom-Button-Orange-to-Purple:hover {
background-color:#8601AF !important;
    border-color:none !important;
}
```

The button I'm trying to modify is the orange one at the bottom of the page here:  [Kidz Haven Daycare](https://kidzhavendaycare.com/) .   The code changes the border of the button to purple which I don't want.

I'm new to adding custom CSS (obviously) and would be grateful for some help!

Comment: Your HTML should include the class `Custom-Button-Orange-to-Purple` and not `Custom-Button-Orange-to-Purple:hover`.

Comment: I made that change.  The only thing that's been changed is that the border-color is changed to purple oddly.

Comment: Please share a [mcve], preferably as a stack snippet. That will make it easier for the community to help you.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean.  I am working in Wordpress.  Can you explain how I would do this?  (looked at the link but didn't see a connection to Wordpress).

Comment: Please have a look [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do)

Answer (score 0):

This is what your CSS looks like, which is absolutely wrong:

```css
.wp-block-button:hover .Custom-Button-Orange-to-Purple:hover has-custom-font-size:hover {
    border-radius:8px;
    background-color:#8601AF !important;
}
```

Also, there is no element with the class `Custom-Button-Orange-to-Purple`.

This is what I understand from your question: You have customized the style of usual buttons, and now you want to style a button which should look different. If so, this may help:

```css
.btn-default {
  width: 100px;
}

.btn-default:hover {
  background-color: skyblue;
  color: #fff;
}

.btn-special:hover {
  background-color: purple;
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<button class="btn-default">Normal Button</button>
<button class="btn-default">Normal Button</button>
<button class="btn-default btn-special">Special Button</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

This took a full days worth of hunting and trying different methods.  What I did was to get rid of the class name I had added to the "Advanced" tab where I created the custom button.  Instead I added HTML to the block on the page where the button would appear.  I used a div container as well to be able to center it on the page.

HTML added to the block with new class names:

```
<div class="Center-Aligned-Custom-Button-Orange-to-Purple">
```

WHY KIDS HAVEN DAYCARE

ADDITIONAL CSS:

```
.Center-Aligned-Custom-Button-Orange-to-Purple {
display:flex;
justify-content:center;
align-items:center;
    
}

.Custom-Button-Orange-to-Purple {
border-radius:8px !important;
font-family:Roboto !important;
font-size:15px !important;
font-weight:500 !important;
line-height: 25px !important;
padding-left: 15px!important;
padding-right: 15px!important;
padding-top: 1px !important;
padding-bottom: 1px !important;
text-align: center !important;
background-color: #FB9902 !important;
color: #fff !important;
position: absolute !important!;
}
```

I'm not certain if I "needed" to use the !important but given the amount of time it took to figure this out, I figured it was better safe than sorry!

Thanks for the responses.  I'm a total newbie, so some comments were over my